# TFS 2017 Build Quality Handler

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk, tfs-2017

we have just upgraded to TFS 2017 from 2013. We had a custom plugin that ran when we changed the build quality. Since the upgrade it doesn't fire. we have tried changing the required DLLs to use the The 2017 client dlls. but the build quality handler does not trigger the plugin. it uses the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ISubscriber interface. We do not get any exceptions as well on the tfs server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISubscriber implementation needs to be recompiled against the TFS 2017 Server as well as Client object model.

And it's important to understand that the new build infrastructure (the non-xaml builds) likely trigger a different set of notifications. At least they're not queryable with the old Client Object Model IBuildServer, you need to use the new REST API.

Without knowing more about your setup (what type of builds, the exact versions of the object model you're binding against, what permissions the TFS Service user has) it's hard to tell where this is going wrong. We have a troubleshooting guide for the TFS Aggregator (https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/wiki/Troubleshooting) which is also a ISubscriber plugin, it may help you debug your setup.

Comment: Thanks I will try to use the info you gave me to figure it out. the code is in one cs file which is very generic. i put i link for it here:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzkkRUeu6KQ1NnNlOFZyN3ZObmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What type of builds are you using? XAML builds? Or the new web based builds?

Comment: this is currently for the XAML Builds. we haven't converted them to the new builds yet.

Comment: OK, for those the code seems OK. Though shelling out to powershell.exe from the web service isn't considered a good practice. I suspect you may need to compile against the latest bits from your tfs server installation.

Comment: This did work one last thing I did was also to upgrade the projects .NET version to 4.9